# Passing Pointer of Two Dimensional Object Array to method

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, methods

I have a class A where I need to implement a new methodB which has to operate on two Object* and I just can't figure out the correct signature for methodB. I found out how to pass a two-dimensional array but not if it's a pointer too. I hope somebody can help me and explain the problem behind this.

```
class A
{
  Object* varA[10][10];
  Object* varB[10][10];

  methodA() 
  {
    varA[0][0] = something...
    ...

    methodB(varA,  varB);
  };

  methodB(Object* input[10][10], Object *output[10][10]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
void methodB( Object* input[][10], Object* output[][10]);
```

but it looks just awful.

Have you considered `std::vector`?